# What kind of information can Google get when I sign in using a Google account?

Tags: gmail, privacy, web-application, google-accounts

When I sign into a website using a Google login, what kind of information can Google see? For example on a website like Trello or StackExchange, can Google access all of my posts and personal information?

Also, when I add an application to GMail for doing something like reading PDFs, can the application vendor view all of my emails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Websites are using Google login as a SOS(Single Sign On ) option. where they can login using the credentials. But they can not access the information and data in that website. Also Google wont allow third party applications to access mails though they can be used as a util. The Util can not do it by their own until unless they are using API calls to read all the mails provided by Gmail.

Note : It will good to read the terms and condition in license agreement of each plugins before you install it.

Comment: I tend not to trust "terms and conditions" to protect me, as those can change without notice. I would be much happier if they had no technical way of accessing data!